# c# add object to listbox and show string of object in it

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a ListBox and adding objects to it.

The object contains 2 variables, let's say username and userid.

How can I add the objects in the list (like
listbox.Items.Add(object);)
and show the username of that object?

Thnx!

Answer (score 44):

You can use the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) properties to display the `UserName` property of your object and use its `UserId` property as the list item value:

```
class YourItem
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

yourListBox.DisplayMember = "UserName";
yourListBox.ValueMember = "UserId";

yourListBox.Items.Add(new YourItem {
    UserName = "FooName",
    UserId = "FooId"
});
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the DisplayMember property of your listBox.

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "username";
```

There is also an equivalent property to define the actual value, that you could use to retrieve the userid. For example if you define your list like this:

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "username";
listbox.ValueMember = "userid";
var item1 = new MyType { username = "user1", userid = "id1" }; // Create an item for the list

listbox.Items.Add(item1); // Add the item
listbox.SelectedIndex = 0; // Selects the first item
```

Then you can reference the objects in the list by 3 different ways (item, value or text) like this:

```
MyObject newItem = (MyObject) listbox.SelectedItem; // Gets the selected MyType
// OR
string username = listbox.Text; // Gets the selected user name using the DisplayMember property of the listbox
// OR
string userid = listbox.SelectedValue; // Gets the selected user's userid using the ValueMember property of the listbox
```

You can also set the selected item the same 3 different ways:

```
listbox.SelectedItem = item1;
// OR
listbox.Text = item1.username;
// OR
listbox.SelectedValue = item1.userid;
```

Comment: `string userid = listbox.SelectedValue` ONLY works if you set the ListBox.DataSource

Answer (score 2):

You can override "ToString" method.

```
class User
{
    public string username { set; get; }
    public string userid { set; get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

```
ListBox a = new ListBox();
a.DataTextField = "username";
a.DataValueField = "userid";
```

To add using `.Add` method you can use:

```
a.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Value = User.ID, Text = User.Name });
```