# Insert Hidden Character to String

Tags: vb.net

I am populating a listbox with results based on a Select statement hitting a SQL server. I am currently adding * to a string if it meets certain criteria. But I realized, this looks sloppy. Is there a way to add a hidden character to a string and then look for that character later?

Here is my current code:

```
If FormType.Level = 10 then
Mystring = "*" + Mystring
end if

If instr(Mystring, "*") > 0 then
Msgbox("Alert! This is a special circumstance!")
end if
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your program works but I would have a property IsSpecialCircumstance set to true or false.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than put strings in the listbox, fill the listbox with custom objects. You can have a boolean value on the object that determines special circumstants.

[c# add object to listbox and show string of object in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489129/c-sharp-add-object-to-listbox-and-show-string-of-object-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store your "special circumstances" in another place, for instance a `List(Of String)`?