# Add item listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, listbox

How can I make a listBox in C# where the item is a object with 3 variables(2 strings,1 int)?The text would be one of the Strings while the Value would be 1 string and 1 int.
I saw how to make with 2 variables here:
[c# add object to listbox and show string of object in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489129/c-sharp-add-object-to-listbox-and-show-string-of-object-in-it)

The has object has

```
 class myItem
    {
        int nSomething;
        String name;
        String tMethod;

        public myItem(String name,int nSomehting,String tMethod)
        {
            this.nSomething = nSomething;
            this.name = name;
            this.tMethod = tMethod;
        }
    }
```

If I set:

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "name";
listbox.ValueMember = "nSomething";
```

would I be able to get "tMethod" with this?

```
listbox.SelectedItem.tMethod
```

Also,when I add the item for the listbox,how can i make sure its unique(just the name is enough)?

Comment: Why do you need the other value to be int?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "listbox.DataSource" with "myItem"-List ?

Than you can catch the other members of you item...