# c# how to add an object to my listbox but display a string

Tags: c#, listbox

I know my question might be already asked, but no given answer worked for me.
I have a class named "Item" and I want to add Items to my listbox, but with strings displayed like myItem.name.
I tried the suggested solution at this question
[c# add object to listbox and show string of object in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489129/c-sharp-add-object-to-listbox-and-show-string-of-object-in-it)
which is:

```
listBox.DisplayMember = myItem.name;
listBox.ValueMember = myItem.id;
listBox.Items.Add(myItem);
```

but it keeps displaying namespace.Item not the item's name.

Also I added MouseEventHandler on MouseClick, how to get selected item in listBox_MouseClick function
Any idea please!!!

my class code:

```
class Item
{
    public string name;
    public Item parent;
    public List<Item> sons = new List<Item>();
    public int depth = 0;
    public int id = 0;

    private static int nextID = 0;

    public Item()
    {

    }

    public Item(string Path)
    {
        this.name = Path;
        this.parent = null;
        this.sons.Clear();
        this.depth = 0;
        this.id = nextID;
        nextID++;
    }

    public Item(Item Parent, string Path, int Depth)
    {
        this.parent = Parent;
        this.name = Path;
        this.sons.Clear();
        this.depth = Depth;
        this.id = nextID;
        nextID++;
    }

    public bool isRoot()
    {
        bool root = false;
        if (this.parent == null)
            root = true;
        return root;
    }

    public bool isFile()
    {
        bool file = false;
        if (this.sons.Count == 0)
            file = true;
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class lacks a nice ToString method!

Comment: Shall I override the ToString method?

Comment: @waelrazouk what happens if you do? :)

Comment: It worked!
But why? where am I using ToString Method?

Comment: you don't use it, the `ListBox` does to display the content

Comment: Since every object in C# inherits from the class `Object` it will have by default a `ToString`method, because `Object` has it implemented. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) but it displays only the class information. by overriding it you choose what to display yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the `ToString` method in your `Item` class to make the ListBox display what you want. Because it uses the default ToString method of the class which displays what you see.

try this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // choose any format that suits you and display what you like
    return String.Format("Name: {0}", this.name);
}
```

and use your regular approach

or use binding to get your items into the `ListBox`. You would need a `List` with your Items

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
// populate it with you items and in the end
// bind it to the data source
this.listBox1.DataSource = itemList;
```

in any case you have to override the `ToString` method.

If you want to change your `itemList` don't forget to refresh the `ListBox`:

```
listBox1.Refresh();
listBox1.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# 6 you can do it like this

```
listBox.DisplayMember = nameof( myItem.name);
listBox.ValueMember =nameof( myItem.id);
```

---

**Update**

If not use

```
listBox.DisplayMember =  "name;
listBox.ValueMember ="id";
```

---

Also bind your data instead of adding them one by one like this:

```
listBox.DataSource = myList;
listBox.Databound();
```

**Update 2**

If you don't want to use datasource, you have to add data 1 by 1 like this. you have nothing to do with display member, etc:

```
listBox.Add(new ListBoxItem(myItem.Name,myIten.Id.ToString()));
```

Comment: It didn't recognize "nameof"

Comment: @waelrazouk are you using c# 6? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

Comment: What do you mean "c# 6"? I have visual studio 2010

Comment: @waelrazouk then you are using c# 4 :).

Comment: Did you try giving the list as the datasourse?

Comment: @waelrazouk try it then.

Comment: @waelrazouk. look at update 2 if you don't want to work with data sourse

Comment: I've tried that. But while I was searching for a solution, I read that ListBoxItem only works in wpf and not in win form

Answer (score 1):

you should use the field name , not the field value

```
listBox.DisplayMember = "name";
```

same for id

```
listBox.ValueMember = "id";
```

Comment: you mean like this? <listBox.DisplayMember = "name";> <listBox.ValueMember = "id";>
It didn't work either

Comment: coulde you please ,add to your question , the myItem class declration