# Removing items from listBox over time - C#;

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm currently working on a chatting program and the idea is to make it a secret one (Kind of like Facebook has the secret chat function).

My messages are sent to a `listBox` component and I want that every 10 or 'n' seconds the oldest message would get deleted. I 
was trying to mark every message with an index but didn't quite understand how that works.

What I'm asking if maybe you guys know a function or could help me write one that does just that. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Windows Forms, C#.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide us some code, then we can try and help you improve it.

Comment: Please add winform tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you have a `ListBox`, the items are all indexed since it's an object collection (an array of objects). Starting from 0 and going upwards for newer entries.

So let's say we add 3 items to our `ListBox`

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Item 1"); //Index 0
listBox1.Items.Add("Item 2"); //Index 1
listBox1.Items.Add("Item 3"); //Index 2
```

All you would have to do, is create a thread that runs in the background that deletes the item at index 0 (the oldest entry) each time.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   while(true)
   {
       if(listBox1.Items.Count > 0) //Can't remove any items if we don't have any.
       {
           Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0))); //Remove item at index 0.
           //Needs invoking since we're accessing 'listBox1' from a separate thread.
       }
       Thread.Sleep(10000); //Wait 10 seconds.
   } 
}).Start(); //Spawn our thread that runs in the background.
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# WinForms a ListBox contains ListBoxItems which are a ObjectCollection ([msdn-link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx))

So you can add any Object you like, the message which will be displayed comes from the DisplayMember

So for example

```
public class MyMessage {
    public DateTime Received { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string DisplayString 
    {
        get { return this.ToString(); }
    }
    public string ToString() {
        return "[" + Received.ToShortTimeString() + "] " + Message;
    }
}
```

can be added as ListBoxItem.

Setting the DisplayMember to `"DisplayString"` ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489129/c-sharp-add-object-to-listbox-and-show-string-of-object-in-it)) will get you the correct output.

now you can iterate through the ListBoxItems, cast them as `MyMessage` and check the time when they were received.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you thought about this but here's a way you could achieve this task.

First create an `List` of `strings`

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
```

To use the List feature you will have to include collections in the form

```
using System.Collections;
```

Now comes the tricky part.

First declare a static integer variable globally i.e. outside all classes.

```
static int a;
```

Whenever you receive a message(considering your messages will be in string format) you've to add that string to `list1` which you created.

```
list1.Add("the received message");
```

Now you've to declare a Timer (If you're new, check out how timers work). Windows forms already has timers, using that will be preferable.
The timer sends a Tick event after the desired time.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         a = list1.Count() - 1;  //Count will return the number of items in the list, you subtract 1 because the indexes start from 0
         list1.RemoveAt(a);
         listBox.Items.Clear();
         foreach(string x in list1)
         {
              listBox.Items.Add(x);
         }
    }
```

What this code will do is, at every `Tick event` of the `timer` it will refresh the listbox, remove the last element from the array, and refill the listbox with the rest.

To use the timer just drag and drop it on the form. It's all GUI based and easy to figure out.

Let me know if you've doubts.

Tip: Make maximum use of `try{}` &  `catch{}` blocks to avoid app crashes.

Comment: Depending on the order of the items in `listBox` you might want to use `listBox.Items.Append` or `.Insert`. Saves some time compared to the foreach, that recreates the whole list.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel It saves time, but it is not the requirement. The listbox needs to be cleared and then refilled without the last message. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Can you not just remove the last item from `Items` and the listbox will reflect the change? Do you really have to refill the items list for a redraw?