# C# Extract a specific part from list box and perform further operation on it

Tags: c#, user-interface, replace, listbox

[image]

`Order item` will move data from `list box items` to `list box order` and quantity of each ordered item is provided in text box. If `qty` for burger is 2 than in `list box order` it is saved as.

```
Burger#2#100
```

i can transfer a selected item but how to extract that specific number and then multiplying it ... confused
here nothing is hardcoded and basically i have to write code for the button which will multiply the quantity with amount present in the list box i was trying the following:

```
 private void btnorder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //int index = listboxitem.SelectedIndex;

            string itemadd = listboxitem.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(" ", "#");
            listboxorder.Items.Add(itemadd);

            string item = listboxitem.SelectedItem.ToString();
          //  string[] text = listboxitem.Items.Replace(" ","#");
           
        }
```

Comment: You have a datagridview there; is it bound (databinded) to anything?

Comment: nope i am only limited to the list boxes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) on your input to get the values separated out by spaces into a string array.  Afterwards, you'll need to convert both the cost and quantity to integers with [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) so you can do math with them.  Then you'll replace the cost in the string array with the computed total and put the string array back together with [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) using "#" as the separator.

Might look something like:

```
private void btnorder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listboxitem.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return; // nothing was selected

    string[] values = listboxitem.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
    if (values.Length == 3)
    {
        int itemCost, quantity;
        if (int.TryParse(values[2], out itemCost) && int.TryParse(textboxquantity.Text, out quantity))
        {
            if (itemCost >=0 && quantity > 0)
            {
                int totalCost = itemCost * quantity;
                values[2] = totalCost.ToString();
                string order = String.Join("#", values);
                listboxorder.Items.Add(order);
                return;
            }                    
        }
    }

    // something went wrong
    // either the item was formatted incorrectly
    // or the item cost or quantity was not a valid integer
    MessageBox.Show("Error Adding Item");
}
```

Comment: I hope this is some kind of assignment, or just learning to code, as this is definitely not the way to do it in a production environment.

Comment: Yeah.  String Manipulation for the most part is a code smell indicating that there's a better was to handle the data.

Comment: what is the purpose of (values.Length == 3) here

Comment: The input is being split on spaces.  For example, your input of "Pizza Rs 1200" would result in an array `{"Pizza", "Rs", "1200"}`.  We are expecting to find the cost of the item at Index 2, so the length of the array must be at least 3 for this to happen.  If the length is not 3, then the input was not formatted as expected.

Comment: There are other ways to extract the item cost.  You could use Regular Expressions, search backwards in the input for the last space, etc..

Comment: what does that **out** means?

Comment: for the cost i can simply multiply the prices set on indexes ...

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create a MenuItem class or struct with the following properties:

```
 String Name;  //Pizza  
 int Price; // 1200  
 public override String ToString()  
 { return Name + " " + "Rs " + Price; }
```

Depending on how you're doing this, you may want to add an ID field.

Build and add these items to the listbox, with

See: [Adding objects to a listbox (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489129/c-sharp-add-object-to-listbox-and-show-string-of-object-in-it)

Step 2: Create an OrderItem class,

```
 MenuItem item;
 int quantity;
 public OrderItem(MenuItem menuitem, int quantity) { //errorcheck and populate fields}
 public override String ToString()
 {  return item.Name + "#" + quantity + "#" + item.Price * quantity;}
```

Step 3: Create the order click handler

```
private void btnorder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
     MenuItem itemadd = (MenuItem)listboxitem.SelectedItem;  
     int quant = Convert.ToInt32(textboxQuantity.Text); // needs validation and exception handling  
     OrderItem oitem = new OrderItem(itemAdd, quant);      
     listboxorder.Items.Add(itemadd);  
}
```

This a first pass look at the problem, but as I have no idea where the data is coming from, I'm keeping it pretty basic.

You will probably want to change the quantity text box to a drop down or other control that constrains inputs to ints.

Comment: thanks alot for the concern :) i wasn't just able to replace and split the string your help would mean alot :)